# How to derive zero conditional mean $E(u|x)=E(ux)=0$ in OLS

Tags: statistics, expected-value, conditional-expectation, regression, least-squares

[image]

Here is the capture from Youtube vedio, I've seen assumptions as $E(u)=0,\,E(u|x)=0$, but I have no idea where does $E(ux)=0$ comes from, how to derive this one.

Appreciate for any help

[Zero conditional mean of errors](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EBg90z--Pyg&t=72s&loop=0)

Comment: E[X^{1}u|X]=X^{1}E[u|X]=0$. Take expectation on both sides.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Isn't $E[Xu|X]=E(X)E[u|X]=0$ already? Why there is no $E $ operate on $X$

Comment: When conditioned om $X$ it behaves like a constant so it can be taken out of the expectation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $E[u|X]=0$ holds and use the law of iterated expectation
$$
E[Xu] = E[E[Xu|X]] = E[X[E[u|X]]=E[X\cdot 0] = 0
$$